# Why/how was this post deleted?

Tags: discussion

See the post [*"Passive circuit to rectify pulse signal"*](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/77432/4512).

This question clearly had some problems, and I both downvoted and voted to close it.  The downvote was for general sloppiness, pre-supposing a answer, and leaving out stuff that should have been obvious that it would be relevant or useful.  The close vote was because it was difficult to tell what was being asked.

However, after some comments, the OP added more information to the question and a reasonable answer was possible.  4 votes to close and 3 downvotes had accumulated until the question finally got to a answerable state.  I have no problem with that since it was a mess originally.  I you don't like the downvotes or the chance your question will be closed before you fix it, write a better question in the first place.

I started to write a answer, but then a banner popped up that the question had been deleted.  I thought maybe the OP got frustrated, but is was deleted by community.  That's the part I don't understand.  First, I don't see the reason for deletion, considering by that time the question had been salvaged.  Second, how can community delete a question so quickly that hadn't even been closed and had only 3 downvotes?  If a mod did it, then isn't the mod's name shown?  What is the mechanism by which community can delete such a question?

Comment: Deleted by community ususally means deleted by spam or offensive flags, or the parent user was deleted and the post had a score of -1 or lower.

Comment: Related to such questions: There is now an option to "Retract close vote". Not sure when this very useful feature appeared, or perhaps it always existed, just never showed up for me.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh This is a recent addition - maybe 1-2 weeks old. Basically, you can cancel your close vote, but you can't vote to close it again

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, It looks like you downvoted his question, harrassed him, and then he deleted his account. Since you downvoted his question so much, the question was automatically deleted when  he deleted his account.

Comment: So when a user deletes his own account, any negative questions are automatically deleted by "community" as well?  I hadn't noticed that the user was gone, but I see now that the user name can't be clicked on.  I was going to give the guy what I think would have been a useful answer.  Oh well, if he has such a short attention span and can't handle the result of writing a mess, then it's just as well I didn't give him his cookie.

Comment: @OlinLathrop that, or he went to one of hundreds of other sites where someone was friendly.

Comment: @Kortuk: My point is good riddance if that's how he's going to react.

Comment: @OlinLathrop You basically did your *"this is crap, go away"* act, got surprised when he *did* leave, and now you're saying "good riddance" to cover your ass.
 How much abuse do you expect a reasonable person to take? He's coming here to ask a question, not to give up his dignity.

Comment: @W5VO: There were serious problems with his question as originally written.  Note that 2 other people downvoted it and 3 to close, so this was not just my off-the-deep-end opinion.  I even wrote a lengthy comment explaining some problems and how to fix them, which got 2 upvotes.  It is wrong to characterise this as "harrassement" and "abuse".  I was writing a answer when the Q got deleted, and that was even *after* he tried to argue about units instead of just fixing it.  As for the OP's dignity, that's not my job.  The bad units and missing information left little of that anyway.

Comment: @W5VO (And OP): Shouldn't the new close/hold system help this also? I mean: it will tell him that it is unclear or whatever and that there is still hope, although you can't control comments or votes... although both *can* be constructive criticism if worded right and understood correctly.

Comment: The new close policies have done us virtually no good here.